# TinyMCE show menu on focus

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce, tinymce-4, tinymce-3

I am tinyMCE in my project.

I have two text area. I need to only show the controls for the active one.
I had two options:

1. Have a common control for both.
2. Hide the controls of the inactive editor.

I couldn't figure out the first option.
I went with the second approach.

Now I am able to trigger events when the editor in on focus. 
I need help with removing the menu and tools from the editor when it goes out of focus.

Here is the code as to how I am approaching the second option:

```
setup : function(ed) {
            ed.on("focusout", function() {
                tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceSetAttribute','toolbar','false');
           console.log(tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceSetAttribute','toolbar','false'));
            });
            ed.on("focus", function() {

                });
        }
```

Comment: I am sure whatever I am doing inside the focus out code part is wrong. Appreciate if someone can tell me what should be the code.

Comment: There is no `focuout` event AFAIK, but there is a `blur` event http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/api4:event.tinymce.Editor.blur

Answer (score -1):

This works for tinyMCE 4 (assuming you are using jQuery):

```
setup: function(editor) {
    editor.on("init", function() {
        editor.contentParent = $(this.contentAreaContainer.parentElement);
        editor.contentParent.find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
    });
    editor.on('focus', function () {
        editor.contentParent.find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").show();
    });
    editor.on('blur', function () {
        editor.contentParent.find("div.mce-toolbar-grp").hide();
    });
}
```

Minor note: You can also use `angular.element(...)` in place of `$(...)` if using AngularJS.